# Go-github not retrieving tag names correctly

Tags: go, go-github

I have the following simple golang code which retrieves tags from terraform repository:

```
import (
    "github.com/google/go-github/v48/github"
    "context"
)
func main() { 
client := github.NewClient(nil)
    tags, _, _ := client.Repositories.ListTags(context.Background(), "hashicorp", "terraform", nil)
    if len(tags) > 0 {
        latestTag := tags[0]
        fmt.Println(latestTag.Name)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("No tags yet")
    }
}
```

Which returns a strange hexadecimal value:
`0x1400035c4a0`
And I would want to return:
`v1.4.0-alpha20221207`

Following the official docs, the function ListTags should return the name encoded into a struct:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/github#RepositoriesService.ListTags

Many thanks

I did try to execute a simple GET request `https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/tags` and I can see that the github api returns the tags correctly

Answer (score 1):

IDK why, but I realize the `latestTag.Name` is a pointer and what you're printing is the address of the memory: `0x1400035c4a0`.

You just need to dereference it:

```golang
fmt.Println(*latestTag.Name)
```

Bonus, check `error` with `if` condition that is returned by the function call to avoid having to go something like this:

```golang
tags, response, err := client.Repositories.ListTags(context.Background(), "hashicorp", "terraform", nil)

fmt.Println(response)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    if len(tags) > 0 {
        latestTag := tags[0]
        fmt.Println(*latestTag.Name)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("No tags yet")
    }
}
```